# Automatically enable 'Throttle Javascript timers in background' with Selenium

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, google-chrome, throttling

I'm working on a Selenium project, and I need to open Chrome Canary with ***Throttle Javascript timers in background = Enable imediattely***

I tried a lot of options, I searched in a lot of website, but couldn't find good solution.

This is what I tried:

```
ChromeOptions canaryOptions = new ChromeOptions
{
        UnhandledPromptBehavior = UnhandledPromptBehavior.Ignore
};
canaryOptions.AddArgument("start-maximized");
canaryOptions.AddArgument("enable-intensive-wake-up-throttling");
                
canaryOptions.AddArgument("--intensive-wake-up-throttling-enabled");
canaryOptions.AddArgument("--intensive-wake-up-throttling-enable");
canaryOptions.AddArgument("intensive-wake-up-throttling-enabled");
canaryOptions.AddArgument("intensive-wake-up-throttling-policy=1");
canaryOptions.AddArgument("--intensive-wake-up-throttling-policy=1");
canaryOptions.AddArgument("intensive-wake-up-throttling=1");
canaryOptions.AddArgument("--intensive-wake-up-throttling=1");
canaryOptions.AddArgument("IntensiveWakeUpThrottlingEnabled=1");
canaryOptions.AddArgument("--IntensiveWakeUpThrottlingEnabled=1");
canaryOptions.AddArgument("--show-autofill-signatures");
```

I tried to set this option with Seleniu, but after relaunch, a Chrome console is opened, and browser loose the focus, and webdriver can't work on that new instance of Chrome Canary.

So, any idea how I can open Canary with **Throttle Javascript timers in background = Enable  imediattely ...** ?

Thank you!